# As a man sows, so shall he reap

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrases

Are there any cooler/better-matched/modern phrases to express that you have to recover your own fault or make up your own mistakes by yourself?
I found the phrase in title by search, but I guess the meaning is slightly different.

Comment: The phrase is generally taken to mean that a person must face the consequences of his or her actions; there is no implication of 'recovering fault'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We often say "clean up your own mess" to convey that the author of a bad situation has a duty to correct it, and not expect others to do it for him or her.

Answer (score 2):

In common, modern parlance, you will hear ***you reap what you sow***. Another common expression equivalent in meaning is simply ***(all) actions have consequences***.

*You reap what you sow* [per the ODE](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/you_reap_what_you_sow) means "you eventually have to face up to the consequences of your actions", not that you have to recover on your own or whatever.

Comment: People say "what goes around, comes around".

Answer (score 0):

The modern version of this phrase is "what comes around goes around", karma would be a synonym, and of course the phrase itself comes from the Bible.